# Rails Hotwire actioncable stream in nested turbo_frame_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, hotwire-rails

Following [an article](https://dev.to/nemuba/blog-demo-using-rails-7-hotwire-rails-tailwindcss-stimulus-railsrequestjs-2c7a) I am trying out Rails Hotwire and want to create a simple blog that works like a single-page app (i.e. using `turbo_stream` to crud posts and comments without reloading the entire page). I would also like to play a bit with actioncable at the same time by making the crud actions real-time for all connected browsers.

So far, it is working except for the real-time part of the comments on posts when I display a specific post (i.e. `posts/show`).

It probably has to do with the identifiers I used for the `turbo_frame_tags` and/or the way I `broadcast` but I can't seem to find the answer.
I looked at [this question](https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/nested-frame-and-stream/1990) and also a [GoRails example of something similar](https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/hotwire-realtime-nested-comments/tree/5fb0978d4cb57667ec2cfef735399420841e919e) but it still does not work.

My current `posts/index`

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "posts" %>

<div class="w-full">
  [...]
  <div class="min-w-full">
    <%= turbo_frame_tag :posts do %>
      <%= render @posts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

the partial for each post is as follows:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag post do %>
  <div class="bg-white w-full p-4 rounded-md mt-2">
    <h1 class="my-5 text-lg font-bold text-gray-700 text-4xl hover:text-blue-400">
      <%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %>
    </h1>
   [...]
  </div>
<% end %>
```

the `posts/show` replaces the current partial of each post with a more detailed version:

```
<%= turbo_stream_from @post, :comments %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@post) do %>
  [...]
    <div class="w-full bg-white rounded-md p-4 justify-start mt-1">
      <div class="w-full pt-2">
        <turbo-frame id="total_comments" class="mt-2 text-lg text-2xl mt-2 tex-gray-50">
          <%= @post.comments.size %> comments
        </turbo-frame>
        <%= turbo_frame_tag "#{dom_id(@post)}_comments" do %>
          <%= render @post.comments %>
        <% end %>
        [...]
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

with the respective models being:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :title
  has_rich_text :content
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  after_create_commit { broadcast_prepend_to "posts" }
  after_update_commit { broadcast_replace_to "posts" }
  after_destroy_commit { broadcast_remove_to "posts" }
end
```

and

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  include ActionView::RecordIdentifier

  belongs_to :post
  has_rich_text :content

  after_create_commit do
    broadcast_append_to [post, :comments], target: "#{dom_id(post)}_comments", partial: 'comments/comment'
  end

  after_destroy_commit do
    broadcast_remove_to self
  end
end
```

The `_comment` partial is

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id comment do %>
  <div class="container w-full mx-auto bg-white p-4 rounded-md mt-2 border-b shadow">
    <%= comment.content %> - <%= time_tag comment.created_at, "data-local": "time-ago" %>
    [...]
  </div>
<% end %>
```

as mentioned, real-time on crud for posts work but not for their comments. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. It was just a matter of where to put the stream:

in `show`, `<%= turbo_stream_from @post, :comments %>` should be after the `<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@post) do %>`.

And the `_comment` partial should be like

```
<%= turbo_stream_from comment %>
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id comment do %>
 [...content]
  </div>
<% end %>
```

There is a more detailed explanation on the [hotwired board](https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/broadcasting-to-nested-turbo-frame-tag/3659)